# Cannot connect to wifi in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

Recently I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop but I can't connect to the WiFi. It just repeatedly prompts for a password.

But connecting through a ethernet cable (between my router and the laptop) works fine. Also when I connect to the WiFi through Windows or my phone there aren't any problems.

I've already tried many different things for solving this problem:

- Check if password is correct (multiple times)
- Connect by using the terminal
- Choose different network security
- Write password in clear text in connection file of the WiFi I want to connect to
- Check if W-LAN is blocked (through rfkill)

If have also seen that there have been a few similar questions but none of the solutions to these seem to work for my problem.

Here is some data that might be helpful to solve the problem:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 26 Sep 2020 11:41 CEST +0200

Booted last: 26 Sep 2020 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.4.0-48-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 10:58:49 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1028:0811]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 79)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:4410]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:28c1 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0000:0538   USB OPTICAL MOUSE
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                380928  0
mac80211              843776  1 iwlmvm
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
dell_laptop            24576  0
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,dell_laptop
iwlwifi               331776  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              704512  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
dell_wmi               20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 intel_hid,dell_wmi
dell_smbios            28672  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
dell_wmi_descriptor    20480  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios
wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    32768  4 dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor
video                  49152  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: wlp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          

##### route #############################

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root        8868       1  0 11:21 ?        00:00:09 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Wireless 3165
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.4.0-48-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               29.1654887522.0
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/5
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   99b1a36d-2e6d-4ad6-b0de-9c19f05fb2a1 | HH40V_5667

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         p2p-dev-wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi-p2p
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifiP2P
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         42 (The supplicant is now available)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         40 (Carrier/link changed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID                             BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  IN-USE 
HH40V_5667                       <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  270 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2       no             
DreiNeo_2.4Ghz_E5D3              <MAC 'DreiNeo_2.4Ghz_E5D3' [AC6]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  270 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no              

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: Permission denied

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HH40V_5667.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=HH40V_5667 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=HH40V_5667
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp2s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp3s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     F2F1A41B96C78AE96720E23
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlmvm
vermagic:       5.4.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        69:0F:B2:8C:24:82:6C:28:AB:28:F7:D2:E5:B8:D0:0B:2C:EF:1F:87
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)
parm:           tfd_q_hang_detect:TFD queues hang detection (default: true (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     FAB28EB495445A127E0CC46
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.4.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        69:0F:B2:8C:24:82:6C:28:AB:28:F7:D2:E5:B8:D0:0B:2C:EF:1F:87
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-jf-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-hr-a0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-f0-hr-a0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0-50.ucode
srcversion:     B6DF401BA0F55B3F4BFBFC5
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.4.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        69:0F:B2:8C:24:82:6C:28:AB:28:F7:D2:E5:B8:D0:0B:2C:EF:1F:87
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: 0 (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     548020DDB9CC1C141282FF4
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.4.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        69:0F:B2:8C:24:82:6C:28:AB:28:F7:D2:E5:B8:D0:0B:2C:EF:1F:87
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
disable_11ac: N
disable_11ax: N
enable_ini: N
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
remove_when_gone: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[11521.061136] wlp3s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]> (try 1/3)
[11521.165188] wlp3s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]> (try 2/3)
[11521.269186] wlp3s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]> (try 3/3)
[11521.377121] wlp3s0: association with <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]> timed out
[11542.641568] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
[11797.300949] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Down
[11804.916087] wlp3s0: authenticate with <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]>
[11804.921895] wlp3s0: send auth to <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]> (try 1/3)
[11804.932662] wlp3s0: authenticated
[11804.937696] wlp3s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]> (try 1/3)
[11805.041758] wlp3s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]> (try 2/3)
[11805.145754] wlp3s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]> (try 3/3)
[11805.253757] wlp3s0: association with <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]> timed out
[11817.031714] wlp3s0: authenticate with <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]>
[11817.037453] wlp3s0: send auth to <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]> (try 1/3)
[11817.050880] wlp3s0: authenticated
[11817.053917] wlp3s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]> (try 1/3)
[11817.157908] wlp3s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]> (try 2/3)
[11817.261926] wlp3s0: associate with <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]> (try 3/3)
[11817.369983] wlp3s0: association with <MAC 'HH40V_5667' [AC10]> timed out

########## wireless info END ############
```